# How to turn a Gradle Script Plugin into a Binary Plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a bunch of gradle script plugins like this one https://github.com/docToolchain/docToolchain/blob/master/scripts/exportExcel.gradle and would like to turn them into "real" binary plugins in order to easily distribute them.

I am aware that I can reference the script plugins form a build via http, but that is not as nice as a real plugin.

As I can see, one way to write a plugin is to implement the `org.gradle.api.Plugin` interface. This basically means I would have to rewrite all mit script plugins.

Is there another way to easily turn them into binary plugins? Maybe some kind of wrapper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script seems to be easily convertible to a plugin.

Why do you say you would have to rewrite your scripts? It's basically a matter of chaging some small details and adding all the boilerplate/metadata, as far as I can tell.

I've written quite a few plugins, here's a really simple one: https://github.com/renatoathaydes/pony-gradle-plugin

This is what you need to change to make a real plugin:

1. Create a normal Gradle project for your favourite JVM language.
2. In the `buildScript` block, add a classpath dependency on `com.gradle.publish:plugin-publish-plugin:0.9.10` and apply the `com.gradle.plugin-publish` plugin. [Example](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/pony-gradle-plugin/blob/master/build.gradle#L10).
3. Add a compile dependency on `gradleApi()`. [Example](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/pony-gradle-plugin/blob/master/build.gradle#L31).
4. Add a `pluginBundle` config to the build file. [Example](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/pony-gradle-plugin/blob/master/build.gradle#L91).
5. Create a class implementing the `org.gradle.api.Plugin<org.gradle.api.Project>` interface. [Example](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/pony-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/athaydes/gradle/pony/PonyPlugin.groovy).
6. Configure the plugin inside the `apply` method (which gives you a handle to `Project`). This includes adding any tasks you may need to the project.
7. Create a class extending `org.gradle.api.DefaultTask` (usually) for each task. [Example](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/pony-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/athaydes/gradle/pony/PonyPlugin.groovy#L62).
8. Implement the task's logic in some method, annotate the method with `@org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction`. [Example](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/pony-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/athaydes/gradle/pony/PonyPlugin.groovy#L93).
9. Create a descriptor at `META-INF/gradle-plugins/plugin-name.properties` with an entry like `implementation-class=your.plugin.Class`. [Example](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/pony-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.athaydes.pony.properties).

That's basically it!

You might probably want to make the plugin configurable, the [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:getting_input_from_the_build) show how to do that, but here's their current example for convenience:

```
class GreetingPluginExtension {
  String message = 'Hello from GreetingPlugin'
}

class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  void apply(Project project) {
    // Add the 'greeting' extension object
    def extension = project.extensions.create('greeting', GreetingPluginExtension)
    // Add a task that uses configuration from the extension object
    project.task('hello') {
        doLast {
            println extension.message
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Which then can be used inside the user's build file like this:

```
greeting {
    message = 'Hi'
}
```

To actually publish the plugin in the Gradle Portal, you need to create an account... [see this](https://plugins.gradle.org/docs/submit) for more details. (Or you can just publish it on Bintray, but then it's a little more awkward for your users to apply your plugin - on the other hand Bintray is much better as a repository, so I end up doing both, see the examples above).