# Need help in creating a custom gradle plugin from a repository which has three .gradle files

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

We have a github repository that has three ".gradle" files like abc.gradle, xyz.gradle, noc.gradle.

Other application repos use above gradle files in their respective build.gradle file like below.

apply from: 'https://github.com/raw/org/repo/abc.gradle?token=ANNCNNCDJNCNJDNCJNCDJ9089NJJ'

Now the requirement is to create a custom plugin out of the github repo that has 3 gradle files and publish it. so that it can be used by everyone like below

apply plugin: 'custom-gradle-scripts'

Please help me with the approach. i am new to gradle and in learning phase.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Sure, actually everything is available in my client machine. Have to type everything manually.  Currently i am following thie link. --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49711846/how-to-turn-a-gradle-script-plugin-into-a-binary-plugin.     Just wanted to check if there is even simpler solution.